# Switch out empty ListView Views in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have a list fragment that does not inflate a custom xml. I'm doing this so that I get the spinning circle progress bar while my content loads from the internet. However, when I receive a network exception, I want to replace the ListView with a TextView that says "Can't be displayed, etc, Press anywhere on the screen to try a reload". How would I do this?

As it stands now, when a network exception is thrown, the circle progress loader just spins and spins and the user has no indication the connection failed. I want to do this IN the view, I don't want an Alert or a Toast, etc. I tried using setEmptyView(myTextView) - but it didn't work, the loading circle was still on the screen instead. And if I define the empty view in an Xml, then the 'loading circle' never shows, which is also not what I want. I want the circle to appear up until there is an exception, and then swap it out with that TextView.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setEmptyView("Error oh noo!");` to display your error like you were trying. You just need to display your `ListView` (with empty contents) for that empty view to show up.

```
setEmptyView("Error oh noo!");
if (isResumed())
    setListShown(shown);
else
    setListShownNoAnimation(shown);
```

Comment: setListShown and setListShownNoAnimation were what i was missing. Thanks, works great!

Answer (score 0):

use setEmptyText() and then you must set an empty adapter on your listView. If you don't set the adapter, then the list will not now that there is no data and thus keep showing the loading circle.

For example :

```
private void onError()
{
    setEmptyText("Network error");
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item));
}
```